# Undefined intel_sse4_strlen

Tags: c, linux, intel, undefined-symbol, sse4

I am running into an issue. After I compiled my program with no problem, then I ran it and got an error that I could not figure out:
[image]

I did "nm -u 64rm | grep intel" and got the following:

[image]

How do I compile or what should I do for these API defined in Text section like this:
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to link an external library that has those function definitions - eg, as `libirc.a' (reference: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/unresolved-external-symbol-_intel_sse2_strlen.html )